# Can Ethereum verify zk-SNARK proofs?

Tags: evm, zksnark, zero-knowledge

I am wondering if the Ethereum Virtual Machine can verify a proof generated from a certain statement? Are there any precompiled contracts for verifying a proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! There is a project called Zokrates, it allows you to create the algebraic circuit necessary for your proof and creates the smart contract that verifies it. You can find the toolbox you can [get Zokrates in github](https://github.com/Zokrates/ZoKrates).

Also, there is a nice tutorial for this [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/practical-zk-snarks-for-ethereum-140cbddcb55d)

hope this helps.

Comment: Does it support RSA Signing algorithm?

Comment: Could you add some explanation regarding the common reference string, and more specifically, the elements required for verification? I guess that's too much information to be saved on the blockchain

Answer (score 0):

ZoKrates is a very good toolbox for zkSNARKs on Ethereum. It helps you use verifiable computation in your DApp, from the specification of your program in a high level language to generating proofs of computation to verifying those proofs in Solidity. In addition to Zokrates, now we have a set of interesting and useful tools for generating ZK-SNARK programs, arithmetic circuits and verification contracts.

- [xJsnark](https://github.com/akosba/xjsnark)
- [circom](https://github.com/iden3/circom)
- [gnark](https://github.com/ConsenSys/gnark)